DaisyUI Custom theme handle disabled button
I'm making a reddit SSO button and am running into an issue where the custom theme I made for the Reddit button turns secondary-grey when it's disabled.
Here is my theme in the tailwind.config
  daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        reddit: {
          primary: "#FF4500", // Reddit primary
          secondary: "#FF5700",
          accent: "#888888",
          neutral: "#3d4451",
          "base-100": "#ffffff",
          info: "#3ABFF8",
          success: "#36D399",
          warning: "#FBBD23",
          error: "#F87272",
          disabled: "#FF450080", // Muted primary color, this does not work
        },
      },
    ],
  }

Here's how it looks non-disabled, everything is good:

But here is how it looks when the button disabled:

Sure I could do an !important or something to override the color, but I'm assuming Daisy should have some way to handle the disabled state via adding a theme or similar.
What is the correct approach to adding a custom color for a disabled button state in Daisy/Tailwind?
And here is the button code for reference
<button
  onClick={onSignin}
  disabled={isAuthenticating}
  className="ml-2 text-white btn btn-primary group btn-block"
  data-theme="reddit"
>
  <div className="z-10">
    {isAuthenticating ? "Signing in..." : "Sign in with"}
  </div>
  <RedditIcon className="h-6 -ml-2.5" />
</button>


As per the source code for Daisy UI's button:
.btn {
  …

  &.btn-disabled,
  &[disabled],
  &:disabled {
    @apply bg-neutral text-base-content border-opacity-0 bg-opacity-20 text-opacity-20;
  }
  @media (hover: hover) {
    &-disabled:hover,
    &[disabled]:hover,
    &:disabled:hover {
      @apply bg-neutral text-base-content border-opacity-0 bg-opacity-20 text-opacity-20;
    }
  }
}

Disabled buttons take their background color from the neutral color. So, you could:

Change the neutral color:
daisyui: {
  themes: [
    {
      reddit: {
        …
        neutral: "…",


Have a custom rule in your CSS that overrides this rule:
.btn-primary:is(.btn-disabled, [disabled], :disabled) {
   background-color: …
}


Use some Tailwind class
<button
  …
  className="ml-2 text-white btn btn-primary group btn-block disabled:bg-<color>"




oh, I thought the color I had listed has neutral was just the default fallback color for disabled. That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

This is another way for whom want to have customized button component:
import clsx from 'clsx'
import React from 'react'

interface ButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  className?: string
  children?: React.ReactNode
  loading?: boolean
  iconStart?: React.ReactNode
  iconEnd?: React.ReactNode
  disabled?: boolean
  size?: 'sm' | 'md' // Add size prop
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  className,
  children,
  loading,
  iconStart,
  iconEnd,
  size = 'md', // Default size
  ...props
}) => {
  const sizeClasses = {
    sm: 'h-btn-sm text-base',
    md: 'h-btn-md text-lg',
  }

  const colorType = findButtonColorType(className || '')
  const buttonBgDisableColor = colorType
    ? `${colorType.replace('btn', 'bg')}/20`
    : ''

  return (
    <button
      className={clsx(
        'btn font-normal rounded-xl items-center flex',
        sizeClasses[size],
        className,
        // buttonBgDisableColor
        `disabled:${buttonBgDisableColor}`
      )}
      {...props}
      disabled={loading || props.disabled}
      type={props.type ? props.type : 'button'} //if not set, on forms acts like submit
    >
      {iconStart}
      {children}
      {iconEnd}
      {loading && <span className='loading loading-spinner'></span>}
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button

type BtnColorType =
  | 'btn-primary'
  | 'btn-secondary'
  | 'btn-accent'
  | 'btn-info'
  | 'btn-success'
  | 'btn-warning'
  | 'btn-error'
  | 'btn-ghost'
  | 'btn-neutral'

const findButtonColorType = (className: string): BtnColorType | undefined => {
  const classList = className.split(' ') as string[]
  const buttonColorTypes: BtnColorType[] = [
    'btn-primary',
    'btn-secondary',
    'btn-accent',
    'btn-info',
    'btn-success',
    'btn-warning',
    'btn-error',
    'btn-ghost',
    'btn-neutral',
  ]

  return classList.find(cls =>
    buttonColorTypes.includes(cls as BtnColorType)
  ) as BtnColorType | undefined
}

